# Writing to log file based on path in Nginx

Tags: nginx

I want to create an HTTP nginx server which will take whatever POST request comes in

```
/some/path
```

will append the post body to `some_internal_path/some/path.log`

Where some and path would be variables. So `/another/place` would append to `some_internal_path/another/place.log`

How can I do this with nginx?

Comment: POST request body can be saved to a disk via [client_body_in_file_only on;](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_body_in_file_only)